Double value in Excel VBA Do While loop condition
In Excel VBA, I made a mistake. I wanted to code
Do While i < 2 Or Abs(Range("D4").Value) > 0.01

but forgot the last part. So, it was only
Do While i < 2 Or Abs(Range("D4").Value)

This code works, but I wondered what it actually does and how the second condition Abs(Range("D4").Value) is treated?
The www tells me that any non-zero value is treated as true. But the iteration stops after 2 loops when i=2 and the value in cell D4 is -0.000159461. That does not make sense to me, because now it should be Do While false Or true what is effectively Do While true..
Why does the loop stop?

You are right with "that any non-zero value is treated as true". But that's the case only when checking the value in a condition:
If Abs(Range("D4").Value) Then Debug.Print "That's true"

But in your case, you have an expression that needs to be evaluated. You are using the Or-operator, and that can be a logical or an arithmetic (=bitwise) operator (see the documentation), depending on the types you are comparing.
So let's check what we are dealing with:
Debug.Print VarType(i < 2), VarType(Abs(Range("D4").Value))

Gives 11 (vbBoolean) and 5 (vbDouble)
So we have different data types (a boolean and a numeric value) and the VBA engine tries to convert the data types to something "similar" so that it can work with it. In this case, it decides that numeric values are needed, and it needs to be of type Long (a Double cannot be used in an bitwise operation).
(I < 2) is converted to
-1 (when I = 1). -1 is the number where all bits are 1.
0  (when I = 2). 0 is the number where all bits are 0.
D4 has the value -0.000159461, it is converted to 0
So what you have is -1 Or 0, and in bitwise operation that is -1, which is interpreted as True as it is not zero.
Or you have 0 Or 0, and in bitwise operation that is 0, which is interpreted as False.
The moral of the story: Don't let VBA do implicit type conversion.

Understood. -0.000159461 converted to 0 is simply an unwanted cast to long. And why is i < 2 converted to -1 or 0 respectively?

Because that's how boolean are converted to Long: True is converted to -1, because -1 has all bits set to 1, and False is 0 because all bits are 0 (in fact, boolean values are stored like this). That's the case in most programming languages.

Summary
The expression Do While i < 2 Or Abs(Range("D4").Value) is calculated:

Due to the second operand is a number, 'Or' performs bitwise operation.
Abs(Range("D4").Value) truncates to integer to be prepared for the bitwise operation.
'i < 2' converts to number.
Bitwise Or performs.
Result of #4 converts to boolean.


Try to execute this code:
Sub Test()
  Dim i%
  Do While i < 4
    Debug.Print i, i < 2, (i < 2) Or Abs(Range("D4").Value)
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub

It produces:

0            True          -1
1            True          -1
2            False          0
3            False          0

So, when the result becomes 0 (which is False), the loop ends.
